# How to use dedicated core for spin-waiting Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have latency critical code where I spin-wait. I want to run it on dedicated core (totally I have 12 cores so it's OK to spent one core just for that task).
I've tried to accomplish it this way:

```
    new Thread(Work).Start();

    private void Work()
    {
        Process Proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        ProcessThread Thread = Proc.Threads[0];
        var AffinityMask = 0x0002; // use only the second processor, despite availability
        Thread.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)AffinityMask;
        while (true)
        {
            Iterate();
        }
    }
```

I was expecting that after setting ProcessorAffinity my Thread will always work on the second core and so I will also have 100% at second core.
However in Task Manager I do not see any "100" occupied cores. Why? How to launch spin-wait thread on dedicated core?

**upd** now i think likely this wrong `Proc.Threads[0]`? I need to have `current` thread not `0` thread?

Comment: What you're trying to do is against the very idea of multithreaded programming. If you have a sufficient amount of processing power, it is unnecessary. If you have too little, priority queues are your solution.

Comment: have you tried setting IdealProcessor for the thread? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.idealprocessor.aspx

Comment: @DariuszWawer i do have sufficient amount of power however .NET by some reason do not understand that my thread is spin-wait and better to be run on dedicated core then.

Comment: @javapowered so you are actually attempting to force a busy-waiting anti-pattern, you fail, and you want to use tricks to let the compiler/system do it... Right.

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread` is available, rather than using `GetCurrentProcess()` and combining it with `Procs.Threads[0]`, which gets a static thread, not necessarily the current thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't see 100% just because you've set the thread affinity on that one thread, because the OS will still schedule other threads on that core and your thread will only get a portion of the cycles.

If you also set the Process.BasePriority = RealTime and Thread.Priority = Highest, then you might see something *close* to 100% on that core. (I wouldn't recommend this in production code).

Depending on *how* time-critical your operations are, the .Net platform might not be sufficient though.

Comment: so there are no way to use "dedicated core for the process or thread" in .NET? if this is only .NET restriction (and possible in other languages like c++) or OS restriction (and possible in Linux) or it is not possble at all in any language and any OS?

Comment: No, you cannot dedicate a core to only run _your_ thread. The OS might still schedule other threads to run on that core. It's not a .Net restriction, it is a Windows thing. Of course, Windows has embedded variants but I don't have much experience in those.

Comment: than can I at least tell .NET to "keep" certain thread on the same core? tell it not to try to move it to another core.

Comment: that, you can do. Setting the process affinity is as simple as setting the `Process.ProcessorAffinity` property but when setting managed thread affinity, you need to use `Thread.BeginThreadAffinity()`. See [here](http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2010/03/08/Running_NET_threads_on_selected_processor_cores).

Comment: thanks code from your link works! now i do see one core 100% CPU load. however i don't know how much latency will i win, i just hope that "avoiding move to another core" is better and faster by definition... (in terms of latency)